# Elfinder/Codeigntier use startPath in view

Tags: php, codeigniter, elfinder

I just integrated ELFinder and it is working great.  I am using [the codeigniter implementation](https://github.com/Studio-42/elFinder/wiki/Integration-with-Codeigniter-2) which is how I got most of what I have below.  My question is I plan to use this in different views, so how can I choose the folder Elfinder opens up to when loading the view?  I was reading up on [startPath](https://github.com/Studio-42/elFinder/wiki/Connector-configuration-options-2.1#startPath) but I may not be using it correctly. For instance in one view I may need it to open the "Stuff" folder, in another view I may need it to open "Something" folder.

This is the method I have in my Files controller as the tutorial points out (controllers/Files.php):

```
function elfinder_init($startPath = '')
    {
      $this->load->helper('path');
      $opts = array(
        'debug' => true, 
        'roots' => array(
          array( 
            'driver' => 'LocalFileSystem', 
            'path'   => set_realpath('assets/uploads'), 
            'startPath' => $startPath,
            'URL'    => site_url('assets/uploads') . '/'
            // more elFinder options here
          ) 
        )
      );
      $this->load->library('elfinder_lib', $opts);
    }
```

And then lets say I create a "Stuff" view (views/stuff.php) with:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var elf = $('#elfinder').elfinder({
        // lang: 'ru',             // language (OPTIONAL)
        sync: 1000,
        defaultView: 'list',
        customData: {'startPath': 'stuff'},
        url : '<?php echo site_url("Files/elfinder_init"); ?>',  // connector URL (REQUIRED)

    }).elfinder('instance');            
});
</script>

<!-- Element where elFinder will be created (REQUIRED) -->
<div id="elfinder"></div>
```

I have also tried `url : '<?php echo site_url("Files/elfinder_init"); ?>/stuff'` but no luck

Here is my library file (Elfinder_lib.php):

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

include_once dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'elfinder/elFinderConnector.class.php';
include_once dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'elfinder/elFinder.class.php';
include_once dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'elfinder/elFinderVolumeDriver.class.php';
include_once dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'elfinder/elFinderVolumeLocalFileSystem.class.php';

class Elfinder_lib 
{
  public function __construct($opts) 
  {
    $connector = new elFinderConnector(new elFinder($opts));
    $connector->run();
  }
}
```

Comment: `Files` is class or folder name ?

Comment: @HendraNucleo Yes it is the name of the file and class.

Comment: Not under sub folder ?

Comment: No, the path is my-app/applications/controllers/Files.php

Comment: Do you use `.htaccess` to remove `index.php` from url?

Comment: Yes I have removed index.php from config.php and .htaccess

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110739/discussion-between-hendra-nucleo-and-derek).

Answer (score 0):

I needed to edit my Files.php controller file to check for the $_GET request as shown below.

```
function elfinder_init()
    {
        $this->load->helper('path');

        $filePath = 'assets/uploads';
        $startPath = $filePath;
        if(isset($_GET['startPath']) && !empty($_GET['startPath'])) {
            $startPath .= '/'.$_GET['startPath'];
        }

        $opts = array(
        'debug' => true, 
        'roots' => array(
          array( 
            'driver' => 'LocalFileSystem', 
            'path'   => set_realpath($filePath),
            'URL'    => site_url('assets/uploads') . '/',
            'startPath' => $startPath
            // more elFinder options here
          ) 
        )
        );
        $this->load->library('elfinder_lib', $opts);
    }
```

Then I was able to use the customData option in my view file when we loaded elfinder like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var elf = $('#elfinder').elfinder({
        // lang: 'ru',             // language (OPTIONAL)
        sync: 1000,
        defaultView: 'list',
        customData: {'startPath': 'something'},
        rememberLastDir: false,
        url : '<?php echo site_url("Files/elfinder_init"); ?>',  // connector URL (REQUIRED)
    }).elfinder('instance');            
});
</script>
```

[Custom Data Reference](https://github.com/Studio-42/elFinder/wiki/Client-configuration-options-2.1#customData) &
[External Links to Subfolders](https://github.com/Studio-42/elFinder/issues/83)